# Javascript regex or other method to check values

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regx that checks for the following:

```
starts with "prop" or "s.prop" or "evar" or "s.evar" 

immediately follows and ends with a number between 1-75

case insensitive
```

So possibilities are:

```
s.prop(1-75)
prop(1-75)
evar(1-75)
s.evar(1-75)
```

Example values:

```
prop1
prop23
prop75
s.prop44
evar36
s.evar60
```

Values which wouldn't match are `prop76`, `evar100`. In a nut shell I want to identify the strings of either `s.prop1-76` or `s.evar1-75` (with or without the "s.")

***Just to clarify it will be the whole value of the variable and not a substring.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your regex so far so we can help?

Comment: Matching SiteCatalyst properties?

Comment: What delimits variables? Whitespace? Commas? Newlines?

Comment: yes this is part of a wrapper for Adobe Analytics

Comment: Also, you haven't defined what a 'variable' is.

Comment: @Sam - the variable will be a string. example var x = "prop1"

Answer (score 1):

it can be difficult to match numeric ranges. i suggest you match all cases, then split of the numbers, cast it to (int) and check normally with `(x >= 1) AND (x <= 75)`. that will save you the headache of trying to get the regex to match every possibility

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't seem to support look-behind, so this will have to do. You'll need to extract the first match to get the part that you want.

```
/"((s\.)?(prop|evar)([1-6]\d|7[0-5]|[1-9]))"/i
```

Comment: It matches `s.s.prop1` as well. :P

Comment: @thefourtheye, that's intended; it still achieves the functionality Michael asked for. He didn't say he only wanted to match strings with whitespace/newlines around them or anything like that. In fact, it doesn't actually *match* `s.s.prop1` anyway; it only matches the `s.prop1` part.

Comment: @ Sam cases like "prop76","s.propevar12" still evaluate as true

Comment: @MichaelJohns, that's because you haven't defined what should delimit matching strings.